# URL rewrite not working at all

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I installed the url rewrite module in IIS 7.5 and did a simple inbound rule of URL exact match and then I redirect the user..But when I go to the url it does not redirect me at all and it just loads the page..I also checked the web config and I getting this error the element systsem.webserver has invalid chile element rewrite ..here's the web.config xml that I have

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://localhost:8989/pay.htm" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:8989" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Am I doing something wrong here or did I configured the module wrong..I tried to reinstall and repiar but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IIS rewrite is not working with localhost**

Anyway, your rule should look like this

```
<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^/?pay\.htm$" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This is also not working.It just loads the original page and does not redirects.

Comment: Are you trying with `http://localhost:8989/pay.htm` ? Did you try *exactly* it with my rule code ?

Comment: Yeah I am trying with http://localhost:8989/pay.htm ..and I updated the web.config with ur code.

Comment: I forgot to escape the dot in rule. I edited my answer, could you try again ?

Comment: hey thanks that worked..The thing was it doesn't work with localhost for some reaosn..it just bypasses the IIS altogether

Comment: I did. Sorry for not having paid attention to localhost, i must be tired